# Will a book for blender 2.62 work for blender 2.78?

Tags: versions

Will a book for blender 2.62 work for blender 2.78?
Do the updates from 2.62 to 2.78 make the out of version books obsolete and
not worth studying?
Thank you.
Kathy

Comment: It really depends on whats covered in that book. If it's focused on main concepts about modeling, UV unwrapping, texturing etc. It could be ok. But if it's mainly based upon Blender specific features there are some noticeable changes.

Comment: @icandoit you could also try to follow strictly the book, for some part, if needed, just downloading the 2.62 version (for this, you'll need a not too recent pc, though, because starting with 2.77 video card requirements become somewhat higher).

Comment: It also depends on your skill level. I could pick up an old book about Blender and follow along fairly easily, but I would've had numerous problems if I had tried that 5 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the features and commands in 2.62 remain the same in 2.78.  None of the most important features have changed drastically.  Even for the features that have changed, the concepts and terminology used in the book should still be the same, and you should be able to find the new way to do it by a quick internet search.

Blender is remarkable in how backwards compatible it is, and how it doesn't change artists' workflow drastically from release to release.  The last major change was between 2.4 and 2.5, and even so almost all of the features remained close to the same from the artist's perspective.

I remember learning Blender 2.6 with a book intended for 2.49.  99% of the book still worked in the new version, and for the remaining 1% I could Google the new way to do it.

Comment: Just be mindful that some of the items on the user interface will be different or in different places. The logic and workflow hasn't changed substantially. Use the book as an introduction and as a way to get your feet wet. Then using the newer versions is just a matter of a doing a few searches online (use the search box on this site, for example) For other questions you can always ask here.